# Is there enough snow for activities in October in Tromsø?

Tags: snow, animal-riding

I would like to go about the end of October to Tromsø, but it is not clear if there is enough snow for husky rides. Do you recommend it?

Also I do not know if it is reasonable to book it since now or can be done easily on the arrival at the hotel. Any recommendation?